How do Cultivator Colossus and bounce lands interact?
When I play a Cultivator Colossus and play a Selesnya Sanctuary through its effect. Do I continue Cultivator Colossus' effect, or do I need to bounce a land first from Selesnya Sanctuary? Also, if I do bounce another bounce land, can I loop both bounce lands?

You do not bounce any lands until after cultivator colossus's ability has fully finished resolving, after all of the repetitions of drawing and playing lands.
The colossus has an enters the battlefield effect that will trigger once, and part of that ability will repeat. New triggers don't go on the stack until a player would receive priority, but no player receives priority during the resolution of an ability. The rules that cover this are 603.1 to 603.3 and 603.12:

603.1 Triggered abilities have a trigger condition and an effect. They are written as “[When/Whenever/At] [trigger condition or event], [effect]. [Instructions (if any).]”

603.1a A triggered ability may include instructions after its effects that limit what the ability may target or state that it can’t be countered. This text is not part of the ability’s effect. It functions while the ability is on the stack.

603.2 Whenever a game event or game state matches a triggered ability’s trigger event, that ability automatically triggers. The ability doesn’t do anything at this point.
603.3 Once an ability has triggered, its controller puts it on the stack as an object that’s not a card the next time a player would receive priority. See rule 117, “Timing and Priority.” The ability becomes the topmost object on the stack. It has the text of the ability that created it, and no other characteristics. It remains on the stack until it’s countered, it resolves, a rule causes it to be removed from the stack, or an effect moves it elsewhere.
603.12 A resolving spell or ability may allow or instruct a player to take an action and create a triggered ability that triggers “when [a player] [does or doesn’t]” take that action or “when [something happens] this way.” These reflexive triggered abilities follow the rules for delayed triggered abilities (see rule 603.7), except that they’re checked immediately after being created and trigger based on whether the trigger event or events occurred earlier during the resolution of the spell or ability that created them.

The repeating is not part of the trigger condition, so it's not a separate trigger, and the ability says "if you do" not "when you do" so it isn't a reflexive trigger under rule 603.12, which is the way they could create a repeating effect like this as a separate trigger.

I think you should also quote rules showing that abilities that repeat are all part of a single resolution step (rather than being another ability on the stack or something).

@KRyan There isn't a specific rules reference that says instructions to repeat a process on a spell or ability are still part of that spell or ability and not a separate object on the stack. It's written as part of the effect, not as part of the trigger condition.

OK; I’m just surprised, since the Comprehensive Rules are so, well, comprehensive. I would have assumed from the wording that “this process” includes the entire ability, including the triggering and placing the ability on the stack to resolve.

Rule 603.1 says that triggered abilities are worded as "[When/Whenever/At] [trigger condition or event], [effect]. [Instructions (if any).]" The "[effect]" is the only part of that where the "repeat this process" fits, so it must be part of the effect. In addition, MTG has never had an effect or rule that instructs you to put a triggered ability on the stack other than by triggering normally, so that just isn't a thing that could be happening here.

@KRyan they are, but they tell you what is, not what isn't and are meant to cover the general situations. Like Murgatroud said there are rules that cover what does go on the stack.  There's no rules that say this doesn't happen that way, because there would need to be a rule that said it does happen and there isnt.
